# divisibleByThreePairSum, I get pair repeats

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm just beginning to learn javascript and this is my first question on stackoverflow, so feel free to criticize me if i'm approaching this the wrong way.

```
var divisibleByThreePairSum = function(array) {
  var pairs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i++; j < array.length; j++) {
      var sum = array[i] + array[j];

      if (sum % 3 === 0) {
        pairs.push([i, j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return pairs;
}
console.log(divisibleByThreePairSum([3,1,0,2,1,3,2,0]));
```

This gives me the answer;

```
[ [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 6 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 5, 7 ], [ 7, 7 ] ]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

For the second "for" loop, I formatted it like so, (j = i++) as to avoid repeats like [1, 3], [3, 1], but I can't seem to get rid of getting pairs like [5, 5], and [7, 7]. Is there any possible ways to format the code differently so that this doesn't happen? Again, I apologize if this was asked improperly; i'll definitely be using this site more often so please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong "question format" wise, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is `j = i++`. This will assign value of `i` to `j` and then increment value of `i`. This will also result in skipping of alternate values of `i` as it is incremented twice.

```js
for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++){
  for(var j = i++; j< 5; j++){
    console.log(i,j)
  }
}
```

You should rather use `j=i+1`. This will sent next value and will not increment value of `i`

```js
var divisibleByThreePairSum = function(array) {
  var pairs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
      var sum = array[i] + array[j];

      if (sum % 3 === 0) {
        pairs.push([i, j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return pairs;
}

console.log(divisibleByThreePairSum([3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0]));
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was such a small piece of code that changed the problem entirely. Thank you so much for the help!